# In a Min-Cut problem, how many times do i need to run Karger's Algorithm in a given set of nodes?

Tags: algorithms

Question:

Given 22 nodes, how many times do I need to run Karger's algorithm in order to find A min-cut problem within an error range (say, <2 or between 0-1) ?

Comment: Would you care to add some context to your question? For example, why are you particularly interested in graphs with 22 (and not, say, 42) nodes?

Comment: I would add dkaeae questions: why do you want to use Karger's algorithm on such little set of node ? Any other min-cut algorithm is more efficient and EXACT. Is it an exercise ?

Comment: Hey, yes it’s an excersize where we need to calculate how many iterations needed for kargers algorithm under a given set of nodes (22 in this case) with the error rate given.

Comment: We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you **write your thoughts and what you could not figure out**. It will definitely draw more answers to your post. Until then, the question will be voted to be closed / downvoted. You may also want to check out [these hints](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284), or use the search engine at the top of this site to find similar questions that were already answered.

Comment: dear jack, obviously if i knew how to solve it or a way to solve it i wouldn't ask about it, so I can't share thoughts about them as well. this is where the power of the community comes handy. voting down a question doesn't serve future students.

Comment: "An error range (say, <2 or between 0-1)"? Do you mean a cut whose number of crossing edges is at most 1 more than the minimum number? Since Karger's algorithm is a probabilistic algorithm, at least what percentage of correct answers is required when you ask "how many times do I need to run Karger's algorithm"? 75% or 50%?